# An example HTML document wherein Magic Target Names are used?

Tags: html

(Although  is not supported by HTML 5) 
Could someone provide an example HTML document wherein Magic Target Names :"_blank","_parent","_self".  are used?

Comment: What is your question exactly

Comment: An example html document for magic target names ? 2

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ***Magic Target Names***, as you call them, are basic HTML attributes, which exist for as long as I can think. What do they do:

```
<a href="website-content.html" target="_self">A link to some content</a>
```

The `target` attribute provides an option to specifiy, how the browser should handle your click on that link.

```
<a href="website-content.html" target="_self">A link to some content</a>
<a href="website-content.html" target="_blank">A link to some content</a>
<a href="website-content.html" target="_top">A link to some content</a>
```

_self: opens the link in the same window instance

_parent: opens the link in a new window instance

_top: opens the link in the full body window

_blank: opens the link in a new tab